# When should I rewrite my dll when using coyote to write unit test?

Tags: coyote

I am trying to write some unite tests based on coyote.
I found that in the tutorial I should rewrite my assembly before `coyote test` command.

However, when integrate coyote tests into unit test platform using `TestingEngine`, it explored bugs without doing any rewriting manually.

Did I doing the right thing? If I can explore the bug without rewriting assembly, what the operate exactly works for?

Thank you!

Comment: Another question is that how I rewrite assembly in the unit test framework?

Comment: Not to interrupt you, but in my case, when I rewrite the dll, coyote failed to find the bug for me. Instead, if I run it straightly without rewriting, I get the bug every time. Could anyone help me to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the easiest option is to rewrite during your build.

Add the following to `.csproj`.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="rewrite.coyote.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CoyoteRewrite" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="dotnet tool run coyote rewrite$(OutputPath)/rewrite.coyote.json -v info" />
  </Target>
```

You have to put your `rewrite.coyote.json` in your project's root folder (next to your `.csproj` and set the `AssembliesPath` to `.`.

My `rewrite.coyote.json` looks like:

```json
{
  "AssembliesPath": ".",
  "Assemblies": [
    "MySut.dll",
    "MySut.UnitTests.dll",
    "MySut.Coyote.dll"
  ],
  "IsRewritingConcurrentCollections": "false"
}
```